# Calculating dielectric constant of a dielectric sample placed inside a rectangular waveguide

Tags: microwave, waveguide

Im trying to calculate the dielectric constant of a dielectric sample placed inside a rectangular waveguide over a range of frequenices. I used WR90 ( X band ).Using the s parameter data (S11 and S21), I used the Nicholson-Ross-Weir method to calculate the material parameters. But Im not getting a constant value(expected), rather Im getting wide variation in the dielectric constant. Given paper shows what i simulated in CST.

https://repositorio.unican.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10902/9337/NewMethodDetermine.pdf;jsessionid=F4CB2EE66B7B7A891F74C9EE342E0345?sequence=1

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: Sorry sir. I will